# SSIS Expression cannot be evaluated -- why not?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2017, expression, etl

I have variable in an `SSIS package name User::FileFullPathLDR`.
From this variable at run time of the SSIS package I want to extract the file name from FileFullPathLDR and put it in another variable called `User::FileName`.

I have tried all types of combinations to try and get this code to resolve in Expression Builder to resolve except standing on my head with incense burning saying OM 4 million times, and nothing seems to work.

I put the following expression in Expression Builder for the variable User::FileName:

```
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::FileFullPathLDR]),1,FINDSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::FileFullPathLDR] ),"\\",1)-1))
```

From the full path I expect to get the filename similar to: `LDRFile01242019.txt.`

But I keep getting the following error when expression builder parses this statement:

> The length -1 is not valid for function "Substring". The length parameter cannot be negative. Change the length parameter to zero or a positive value.

Comment: More info:  I am clicking on Expression Builder from within the parameters window to the far right of the variable FileName.

Comment: The -1 is being evaluated as negative one, but the intention is to have this evaluated as minus one.  How does one get Expression builder to see it as minus 1 and not negative 1.

Comment: Minus 1 and negative one are the same thing. In this kind of pattern, that error occurs when the `FINDSTRING` part fails to find anything and returns 0. First evaluate just the `FINDSTRING` bit and confirm that it isn't returning 0. Don't try and debug large inline expressions all in one go. Validate pieces of them and build them up.

Comment: If you are doing a lot of funky path / file stuff it may be worth doing it inside a script task and using friendlier methods

Comment: Thanks Nick.McDemaid, I have validated the individual parts, and I get back a file name right now of \LDR01102019.txt if the -1 is not there.   I think I am going to move on and just do a script task because this parser won't allow me to return FINDSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::FileFullPathLDR] ),"\\",1)-1) as one integer for the Substring length parameter, and instead sees the -1 as a final invalid parameter to the Substring function.

Comment: I don't see how it could think that. To me it seems more likey that `FINDSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::FileFullPathLDR] ),"\\",1)-1)` actually returns -1. I just tested your expression with sample data `C:\Folder1\Folder2\FileName.TXT` and it worked fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this expression:

```
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::FileFullPathLDR]),1,FINDSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::FileFullPathLDR]),"\\",1)-1))
```

against this test string:

```
C:\Folder1\Folder2\FileName.TXT
```

and it returned

```
FileName.TXT
```

There was no error

I tested it by creating a variable and defining an expression for it, then evaluating that expression.

Comment: This statement is like the one I have been testing and get the error, but the only difference is that the FileFullPathLDR was a variable with no initial value because this is passed in from the program as multiple files are read in a ForEach loop. Your solution caused me to go ahead and initialize FileFullPathLDR to a dummy value of c:\temp\FileName.txt and then the parser closed fine and I get the correct filename now.  Thanks Nick.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following expression:

```
RIGHT(@[User::FileFullPathLDR],FINDSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::FileFullPathLDR]),"\\",1)-1)
```

Also try to add a conditional operator to avoid bad values errors:

```
FINDSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::FileFullPathLDR]),"\\",1) == 0 ? "" : RIGHT(@[User::FileFullPathLDR],FINDSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::FileFullPathLDR]),"\\",1)-1)
```

**References**

- [SSIS Expression to get filename from FilePath](https://sandeepdhanush.wordpress.com/2012/12/27/ssis-expression-to-get-filename-from-filepath/amp/)
- [SSIS Expression to Get File Name From Full Path](https://waheedrous.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/ssis-expression-to-get-file-name-from-full-path/amp/)

Answer (score 1):

The part `FINDSTRING(@[User::FileFullPathLDR],"\\",1)` returns 0 if FileFullPathLDR does not contain a `\`. Since you are subtracting -1, you might end up with a negative value if your string doesn't match the pattern, or if the variable is set at runtime (you might have an empty string during validation).

If you need it to work with an empty string as well, you could add a `\\` in front of it if there is no `\\` present yet, using something like `FINDSTRING(@[User::FileFullPathLDR],"\\",1) == 0 ? "\\"+ @[User::FileFullPathLDR] : @[User::FileFullPathLDR]`

So the whole thing will be:

```
REVERSE(
    SUBSTRING(
        REVERSE(
            @[User::FileFullPathLDR]),1,FINDSTRING(REVERSE(FINDSTRING(@[User::FileFullPathLDR],"\\",1) == 0 ? "\\"+ @[User::FileFullPathLDR] : @[User::FileFullPathLDR])
            ,"\\",1
        )-1
    )
)
```

So, if there is no `\` present, it will just return the string itself.